# How to check if two objects are identical

Tags: c++

I have a vector containing several objects of the same class. I am trying to loop through the vector and compare each object to one given object and if they are identical return the position in the vector of that object. How would I go about this?

For example I want to find object foo3 in the vector containing [foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5228307/1729885

Comment: [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the `==` operator, and then use it in your comparisons of objects as if they were an item of one of C++'s built-in types:

```
// Overload == for myclass
bool operator==(const myclass& a, const myclass& b) {
    return ...; // true if a is the same as b; false otherwise
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
myclass toFind = ...
std::vector<myclass> items = ...
for (int i = 0 ; i != items.size() ; i++) {
    if (items[i] == toFind) {
        cout << "Item is found at index " << i << endl;
    }
}
```

You can also use other searching facilities built into the standard C++ library. The key to it functioning properly is having a correct overload of the `==` operator.

Comment: When overloading the == operator do I have to explicitly say the case where they are equal? As I may have two objects that have identical attributes yet are different objects.

Comment: @BenMcAlindin `std::vector<myclass>` makes copies of your objects. Once an object is in the vector, it's a different object in memory, so comparing attributes is all you can do, unless you store pointers. If you do store pointers, plain or "smart", all you need to decide if two objects are the same is comparing their pointers with a `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use [***std::find***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) after overloading `==` for your class

`auto it = std::find( vec.begin () , vec.end() , obj ); //eg. obj = foo3`

To get position :

```
int pos  = -1;
if( it != vec.end() )
   pos = it - vec.begin () ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the equal operator for the object... so you can compare them as normal built-in types. 
After that you can use the std::find function